# Xcode Add Delay So Button Press Can Be Registered

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, delay

So I have an application that takes in images from the video camera and displays information to the screen after some processing on the image. I've added a pause button so the user can 'freeze' the most recent results on the screen.

The pause works, but it is one cycle behind. By the time the button press is recorded, the next image is already being processed so the results that are being locked on the screen are actually from the subsequent image. I've tried adding a delay to allow the user time to press pause using:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(waitForPause) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

but this does not perform as I was expecting. Any ideas on how to handle this pause correctly?

EDIT: I've noticed that the AppDelegate file has some functions that appear to handle this sort of thing. Namely, applicationWillResignActive can supposedly be used to pause a game based on the apple docs. Has anyone used this for such a purpose? The method is currently empty. What would I have to add to this method to get it to temporarily pause the app based on a button press?

UPDATE: Here is how I currently implement and handle the pause button press.

```
//Pause Button
self.pauseButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[pauseButton addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(pauseButtonPress:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[pauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
pauseButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 100.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[self.view addSubview:pauseButton];

- (void) pauseButtonPress:(id) sender {

    [pauseButton setHidden: YES];
    [playButton setHidden: NO];
    continueRunningScript = NO;
    NSLog(@"paused");
    NSLog(@"Current Result: %@", result_string);

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I saw your question about this yesterday. Have you tried setting your pause event on `touchesBegan:` rather than `touchesEnded:` so that the pause is fired as soon as the user's finger hits the button? That may be all you need.

Comment: How would I set that up, @Tim Kemp? I've edited my original post to show my current implementation and handling of the pause button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement delays. Try this:

Each time you render a new image to the screen, save the old image in a `previousImage` variable. When the user hits the pause button, simply swap out what is currently on-screen for with the contents of `previousImage`.